# scraping inside script tag with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm scraping data from [e-commerce site](https://www.trendyol.com/apple/macbook-air-13-m1-8gb-256gb-ssd-altin-p-67940132) and I need model number of each laptops. But in div tags, there are no model numbers. I found model number inside script tag as "productCode". For this example its:

```
"productCode":"MGND3TU/A"
```

How can I gather the "productCode" data. I couldn't understand from other posts.

Edit: I find the ‘productCode’ inside script tag. But i don’t know how to get it. You can check from page source.

Comment: Since the content of script tags is not XML, it can't be parsed using BS4. You can always get the content as a string via BS4 and then use a regular expression to find the line containing `"productCode":`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `beautifulsoup` is not needed cause response could be searched directly with `regex`:

```
json.loads(re.search(r"window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__=({.*}});window", r).group(1))
```

##### Example

```
import requests, re, json

r = requests.get('https://www.trendyol.com/apple/macbook-air-13-m1-8gb-256gb-ssd-altin-p-67940132').text
json_data = json.loads(re.search(r"window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__=({.*}});window", r).group(1))

json_data['product']['productCode']
```

##### Output

```
MGND3TU/A
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the JSON is hidden in the `<head>`, it can be parsed, but with some custom logic.

Unfortunately the script tags exports the JSON to a window var, so we'll need to remove that befor we can parse it.

1. Get url
2. Get all `<script>`
3. Check if `PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STAT` exist in the string (valid json)
4. Remove the prefix (hardcoded)
5. Find the index of the next key (hardcoded)
6. Remove after the suffix
7. `Try` to parse to json
8. Print `json['product']['productCode']` if it exists

```py
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


reqs = requests.get("https://www.trendyol.com/apple/macbook-air-13-m1-8gb-256gb-ssd-altin-p-67940132")
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')

for sc in soup.findAll('script'):
    if len(sc.contents) > 0 and "PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STAT" in sc.contents[0]:

        withoutBegin = sc.contents[0][44:]

        endIndex = withoutBegin.find('window.TYPageName=') - 1
        withoutEnd = withoutBegin[:endIndex]

        try:
            j = json.loads(withoutEnd)
            if j['product']['productCode']:
                print(j['product']['productCode'])
        except Exception as e:
            print("Unable to parse JSON")
            continue
```

Output:

```
MGND3TU/A
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because those tags are generated using JavaScript. When you send a request to that URL, you will get back a response which has information for a JS script to build DOM for you. (technically JSON information):

To see what your returned response actually is, either print the value of `r.text` (`r` is returned from `requests.get()`) or manually see the *"view page source"* from the browser. (not inspect element section)

Now to solve it, you can either use something that can render JS, just like your browser. For example [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). `requests` module is not capable of rendering JS. It is just for sending and receiving requests.

Or manually extract that JSON text from the returned text (using Regex or,...) then create a Python dictionary from it.